# Android Camera2 API - Overwrite old images

Tags: android, delete-file, android-camera2, save-image

I am using the code given at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic
and images are being saved in the activity storage with

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile, false);
            output.write(bytes);
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if (null != output) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                    buffer.clear();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

given by the sample code. If I delete the images with

```
   File image_directory = getFilesDir();
    if (image_directory != null) {
        File[] images_list = image_directory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < images_list.length; i++) {
            try {
                //Delete the images files in the given folder
                images_list[i].delete();
                Log.e(TAG, "[-] File deleted with filename: " + images_list[i].getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

and take new images **with the same filename as before**, the old images show up. What`s happening here?

Comment: Try to print exceptions in catch statement into LogCat and see if it gives you anything.

Comment: Nope, nothing. This Log.e(TAG, "[-] File deleted with filename: " + images_list[i].getName()); message is triggered like it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, code is correct. I am using Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to display the images and the lib cached the images based on the image names. While the new images had been stored on the device, the old, cached images have been displayed.

Comment: But i am not using Glide library still has same problem. Can you please tell me the solution?